# Does WebSphere MQ support JMX API?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, jmx

I have a requirement where I need to read the current configuration of WebSphere MQ (cluster config, queue managers, queues, channels, remote queue etc..., the works).
I need to write this tool in Java.
**So is there a JMX API for WebSphere MQ that will allow me to read MQ configuration?**
**Is the config stored in a file (xml? or otherwise.) that I can read?**

MQExplorer shows all the queues, queue managers etc... How does it do it? I am not really interested in queue depth etc... (don't want runtime info) just the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy.
There's nothing as straight forward as a JMX API, or even XML.
The only real way to get the data you're looking for (in Java) other than issuing command line requests and scraping the response is the [Programmable Command Formats](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086860_.htm?lang=en) or PCF. It's the nastiest API I've ever had the displeasure of using, but it is, admittedly, very useful. There's a decent number of examples floating around (not from IBM mind you) but [this one](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html) is the most comprehensive collection I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are PCF Java samples shipped with IBM MQ product. You can find them, on Windows, under `<mq install>\Tools\pcf\samples`. There are samples to query/create/delete queues, channels. These samples definitely help you to get going.

IBM MQ stores the configuration information in binary files, queues etc. PCF classes is the best way to deal with configuration.

Comment: So, is there a PCF to change or add JMX arguments to get JMX enabled?

Answer (score 1):

There is an agent available from Queuemetrix that does what you want.
http://www.queuemetrix.com/lamaxu

The LAMAXU collector is a Java agent that remotely connects to IBM MQ and exposes all its available metrics in an easily consumed format, allowing it to be monitored  by virtually any monitoring system.

1. JMX Mbeans (AppDynamics & Solarwinds)
2. HTTP REST (with formats of both XML and JSON)
3. Log file (XML or JSON formatted logs for consumption by SPLUNK)

Comment: Whilst the link may answer the question, link only answers can become out of date or obsolete if the information in the link changes or is deleted. It would be more prudent to add the information from the link related to this question in the answer and then provide the link as a reference.